# Hibernate: Violation on cascade persist

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two classes, Order and Contact annotated as below

```
public class Order {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "order_id_gen")
      @Column(name = "id_order")
      private long id;

      @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
      @JoinColumn(name = "id_order")
      private List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

}

public class Contact {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "order_contact_id_gen")
      @Column(name = "id_contact")
      private long id;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_order")
        private Order order;

}
```

When I try to save the entire order with a JPA repository like

```
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {}
```

using

```
orderRepository.save(order);
```

I get an exception

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: the INSERT or the UPDATE on table "ms_contact" violates foreign key constraint "fk_4uonv9hs08picha25luywl3on"
Detail: the key (id_order)=(602) is not present in "ms_order".
```

and contacts are not persisted.

Comment: Show the code that creates the order.

Comment: You have both sides of your bi-directional mapping controlling the field.  You need to have the OneToMany 'mappedby' the manyToOne.  Use OneToMany(mappedBy="order") instead, and remove the join column on it.

Comment: Delete the JPA cascade – javax.persistence.CascadeType, replace it with Hibernate cascade – org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade, with CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE.